# Laravel динамическое формирование переменных

Tags: php, html, laravel, blade

Прошу помощи, хочу обернуть формирование блока в цикл:

```
@for ($i=1; $i<=31; $i++)
<span class="badge"
      title="Обновлено: {{ $worksub->prop["d".$i]["updated_at"] }}&#013;
             Комментарий: {{ $worksub->prop["d".$i]["comment"] }}"
      style="color: #ffffff; {{ $worksub->getWeekday($worktimename, str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)) }}">
          {{ str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) }}
          <br>
          @if($worksub->d.$i) {{ $worksub->d.$i }} @else-@endif
</span>
@endfor
```

Но вместо **$worksub->d1** (в строке: *@if($worksub->d.$i) {{ $worksub->d.$i }} @else-@endif* )
получаю просто значение **$i**

Пробовал варианты:

1. $worksub->d[$i]
2. ${'worksub->d'.$i}

без результата

Comment: Используйте массивы и не извращайтесь

Comment: стандартное `$worksub->{"d$i"}` там не работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как и в обычном пхп доступ к вычисляемым именам полей в виде `{{ $worksub->{"d$i"} }}` - вполне рабочий вариант

Comment: Благодарю! Работает!!)